# Set edit mode as default behavior when adding a new item in a tree

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, edit

I have a Treeview which I can do some simple operations like expand, add new item, edit, delete, copy and paste, rename, etc.

What I would want to do is that, when I click "Add item", it creates it and shows up in edit mode, so I can set a new name to it. As it is right now, I just assign a generic name "New Item X".

I hope there is a easy solution for this that I'm missing here. Im working with WPF by the way (I don't think it's necessary to put some code samples here, but if I'm wrong, just say so and I'll edit the post).

Comment: Search for 'treeviewitem editable wpf' on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I used a Refresh() function that is called every second, refreshing the tree. It also handles the AddCommand, so when I try to add a new item, it receives this request, set a EditName property to true and that's it!

OBS: I couldn't see any other way, as I couldn't set the focus to the new created item.